# What settings should I use for IPTABLES so the endorser and baker run properly?

Tags: baker, endorser

I tried using the below IPTABLES config(a few of the ports are changed), however, the endorser missed a block this morning, I think the IPTABLES rules are preventing it from talking to the node, but I'm not sure.

## Allow related connections

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

## Allow loopback interface

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

## Allow SSH for now, so our connection is not disrupted, we will enable/disable SSH access via our security groups on the cloud provider.  We will tighten this up in future versions

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

## Allow Tezos P2P connections

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9732 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9732 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 9732 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

## Allow NBD

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport $MY_NBD_PORT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

## Allow DNS

iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

## Allow NTP

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --source-port 123:123 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --destination-port 123:123 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

## Allow DHCP

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 67:68 --sport 67:68 -j ACCEPT

## Setup loggers

iptables -N LOG_AND_DROP_IN
iptables -A LOG_AND_DROP_IN -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES:DROP:IN:"
iptables -A LOG_AND_DROP_IN -j DROP

iptables -N LOG_AND_DROP_OUT
iptables -A LOG_AND_DROP_OUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES:DROP:OUT:"
iptables -A LOG_AND_DROP_OUT -j DROP

iptables -N LOG_AND_DROP_FWD
iptables -A LOG_AND_DROP_FWD -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES:DROP:FWD:"
iptables -A LOG_AND_DROP_FWD -j DROP

## Log and drop everything else

iptables  -A INPUT   -j LOG_AND_DROP_IN
iptables  -A FORWARD   -j  LOG_AND_DROP_FWD
iptables  -A OUTPUT  -j LOG_AND_DROP_OUT

## Default to drop everything

iptables  -P INPUT   DROP
iptables  -P FORWARD DROP
iptables  -P OUTPUT   DROP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your node is configured using defaults, then your tezos-node should be listening on 127.0.0.1:8732, which you already have a rule to allow (loopback). If the endorser cannot talk to the RPC, it will immediately die and will not start back up so this is easy to test.

What was the message in the endorser? Did you inject the op yet still miss? Did others also miss the same block? Might not have been you at all.

Side note, are you running a DHCP server on this same server? If not, then you don't need that INPUT rule. You would only need OUTPUT to contact your DHCP server if you indeed get auto-assigned IPs.

Comment: There was no injection, and the endorser was running, which is why I thought it was a bit weird....

Comment: If there was no injection, then what did the endorser logs say?

Comment: I looked but there wasn't anything.  It's working today though, maybe it was just bad luck.

Comment: @MackBaise Please mark the answer accepted then so it can be closed out.